# Run app with app.config from other location

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, command-line, app-config

I have app.config file in folder c:\xxx\app.config, but program is in c:\yyy\app.exe folder. I want to run program c:\yyy\app.exe by command line and give config location as parameter. Is it possible without ingratiation in app code?
I would like to get something similar

C:\yyy\app.exe /config:"c:\xxx\app.config"

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632422/how-to-change-location-of-app-config

Answer (score 1):

Batch file command: called runme.bat

```
"C:\yyy\app.exe" /config:"%~1"
```

Launch it like this: `runme "c:\xxx\app.config"`

Comment: I try to use this construction, but it doesn't work. I can't find any docs to '/config' param, could you give me it?

Answer (score 0):

you could do so if you'd use an shortcut to run the app, here you can specify the exe from dir a to run in location to execute b - if that is an option instead of cmd start.

**Edit:**
If your app.exe does not know the switch to load config from another directory you can try to change the working directory by pushd for example. like:

```
...
pushd c:\xxx
c:\yyy\app.exe
...
```