# AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly sets console title

Tags: .net, clr, appdomain

We use `AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly()` to "fork" an executable from itself. That can be used to dynamically update the app.config when starting (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3633158/21567) old post).

Apparently, calling `AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly()` sets the title of the current console window to the `Assembly.CodeBase` value of the assembly being executed. When the function returns, i.e. the execution resumes to the calling AppDomain, the title is reverted back.

While it does no real "harm", it is a little annoying, when you have a large batch file that calls such executable multiple times (the console title constantly changes).

Here is a repro example:

```
using System;

public class Foo 
{
    public static int Main(string[] args) 
    {
        if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Equals("Test")) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside");
            // While "in here", the console title is something
            // like: "file:///C:/Sources/Foo.exe".
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }

        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test", null,
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation);
        return domain.ExecuteAssembly(typeof(Foo).Assembly.Location, (string[])null);
    }
}
```

I was unable to find any documentation on this, or code that could cause this. The actual function would probably by `_nExecuteAssembly()` inside the CLR, which is not included in the open source CoreCLR, because that doesn't support AppDomains. Also, the SSCLI source code *seems* to have no relevant code (albeit I'm not sure, nor can check, if that behaviour could also be seen with the CLR 2.x).

**Updates**:

- Windows applications (compiler switch `/target:winexe`) do *not* exhibit this behavior. To test use this example:

  ```
  // Compile with "csc.exe /target:winexe foo.cs" 
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  public class Foo 
  {
      [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
      public static extern void AllocConsole();

      public static int Main(string[] args) 
      {
          AllocConsole();

          if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Equals("Test")) 
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Inside");
              // While "in here", the console title is something
              // like: "file:///C:/Sources/Foo.exe".
              Console.ReadKey();
              return 0;
          }

          var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test", null,
              AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation);
          return domain.ExecuteAssembly(typeof(Foo).Assembly.Location, (string[])null);
      }
  }
  ```
- Using Mono instead of the Microsoft CLR, does also *not* exhibit this behavior (even when running executables compiled with the Microsoft compiler). So this seems to be a (Microsoft) CLR related behavior.

Can anybody confirm/explain/reproduce this? Can you find traces of this behavior in the source code (of SSCLI, CoreCLR, etc.)?

**Update on Workaround**

<del>(Note: I have workaround for this using `AppDomain.SetData("key", Console.Title)` and `Console.Title = AppDomain.GetData("key")`, respectively, but still I'm curious.)</del>

Since Hans has found the definite reason for this being indeed an explicit call to `SetConsoleTitle` (the native base of `Console.Title`), I wanted to make my workaround explicit:

```
using System;

public class Foo 
{
    public static int Main(string[] args) 
    {
        if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Equals("Test")) 
        {
            Console.Title = (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("foo:original-title");
            Console.WriteLine("Inside");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }

        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test", null, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation);
        domain.SetData("foo:original-title", Console.Title);
        return domain.ExecuteAssembly(typeof(Foo).Assembly.Location, (string[])null);
    }
}
```

In practice, you probably want to do a little more error checking and possible prevent exceptions from `Console.Title` to cause the app to exit, but YMMV.

As Hans said, an as shown in the example above, you could have also compiled as a "Windows Executable" (`/target:winexe`) and manually p/invoke `AllocConsole`. But personally I found the above approach more reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is visible in the CoreCLR source code for the CLR, [src/vm/appdomainnative.cpp, AppDomainNative::ExecuteAssembly function](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/appdomainnative.cpp#L700):

```
if (pAssembly->GetManifestFile()->GetSubsystem() == IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI)
{
    {
        GCX_COOP();
        Security::CheckBeforeAllocConsole(pDomain, pAssembly);
    }
    bCreatedConsole = AllocConsole();
    StackSString codebase;
    pAssembly->GetManifestFile()->GetCodeBase(codebase);
    SetConsoleTitle(codebase);
}
```

This implements the promise that an assembly compiled with /target:exe is displayed in a console window, creating it if necessary.  Probably something you don't see since you are already running from a console mode app.  The `SetConsoleTitle()` call sets the window title.

No knobs to tweak, you have to set the /target compile option to anything else.  Either `winexe` or `library` gets the job done, note that the filename extension does not matter.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Frankly, I don't quite get why I didn't see it in the CoreCLR sources - looked there first and didn't even see the native AppDomain sources. Stupid me :-)  What I don't get is the "why" in it. The `AllocConsole` is granted - assuring the console window is "there", but why setting the title. That would have not been necessary. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: That question is roughly equivalent to "why not?" :)  A non-managed console mode app does this as well, console windows should have an appropriate title.  Console.Title in a .NET program.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. I think I was seeing to whole issue too much from my own point of view, where I use ExecuteAssembly("self"), and thus the title change is somewhat "redundant" (and besides "CodeBase" looks just plain ugly). But yes, the whole "why/why not" question is of course moot :-)